# Subtract the highest value within row containing a pattern against the highest value of row not containing that pattern in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as:

```
Groups Name               Value
G1     BLOC_Homo_sapiens  100
G1     BLOC_Chimpenzee    99
G1     BLOC_Bonobo        80
G1     Canis_lupus        20
G1     Danio_rerio        10
G2     BLOC_Homo_sapiens  30
G2     BLOC_Bonobo        29
G2     Mus_musculus       28
G2     Cules_pupiens      26
G3     BLOC_Gorrilla      300
G3     Cimex_lectularius  10
G3     Bombus_terrestris  9
```

And I would like to add a new column called "`diff_length`" for each `Groups` where I subtract the highest `Value` of the `Name` containing the pattern "`BLOC`" against the highest Value of the `Name` which does not contain the pattern "`BLOC`".

For the **Groups1** for instance, the highest `Value` with the **BLOC** is 100, and the highest `Value` without **BLOC** is 20. So the result is `100-20 = 80`.

I should then get:

```
Groups Name               Value diff_length
G1     BLOC_Homo_sapiens  100   80
G1     BLOC_Chimpenzee    99    80
G1     BLOC_Bonobo        80    80
G1     Canis_lupus        20    80
G1     Danio_rerio        10    80
G2     BLOC_Homo_sapiens  30    2
G2     BLOC_Bonobo        29    2
G2     Mus_musculus       28    2 
G2     Cules_pupiens      26    2
G3     BLOC_Gorrilla      300   290
G3     Cimex_lectularius  10    290
G3     Bombus_terrestris  9     290
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
m = df['Name'].str.contains('BLOC')

df['diff_length'] = (df.groupby('Groups')['Value']
                       .transform(lambda d: d.where(m).max() - d.mask(m).max())
                    )
```

*NB. this assumes unique indices.*

Output:

```
   Groups               Name  Value  diff_length
0      G1  BLOC_Homo_sapiens    100         80.0
1      G1    BLOC_Chimpenzee     99         80.0
2      G1        BLOC_Bonobo     80         80.0
3      G1        Canis_lupus     20         80.0
4      G1        Danio_rerio     10         80.0
5      G2  BLOC_Homo_sapiens     30          2.0
6      G2        BLOC_Bonobo     29          2.0
7      G2       Mus_musculus     28          2.0
8      G2      Cules_pupiens     26          2.0
9      G3      BLOC_Gorrilla    300        290.0
10     G3  Cimex_lectularius     10        290.0
11     G3  Bombus_terrestris      9        290.0
```

Alternative syntax:

```
m = df['Name'].str.contains('BLOC')

df['diff_length'] = (
  df['Value'].where(m).groupby(df['Groups']).transform('max')
 -df['Value'].mask(m).groupby(df['Groups']).transform('max')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# identify rows that contains the block
m1=df['Name'].str.contains('BLOC')

# groupby on Groups and the rows that has BLOC and ones that don't
# take the max for each (TRUE/FALSE) in a group, and take diff
df2=df.groupby(['Groups', m1 ] )['Value'].max().diff().reset_index()

# create a dictionary
d=dict(df2[df2['Name'].eq(True)][['Groups','Value']].values)

# map difference back to the df
df['diff_length'] = df['Groups'].map(d)
df
```

```
    Groups  Name          Value      diff_length
0   G1  BLOC_Homo_sapiens   100      80.0
1   G1  BLOC_Chimpenzee      99      80.0
2   G1  BLOC_Bonobo          80      80.0
3   G1  Canis_lupus          20      80.0
4   G1  Danio_rerio          10      80.0
5   G2  BLOC_Homo_sapiens    30       2.0
6   G2  BLOC_Bonobo          29       2.0
7   G2  Mus_musculus         28       2.0
8   G2  Cules_pupiens        26       2.0
9   G3  BLOC_Gorrilla       300     290.0
10  G3  Cimex_lectularius    10     290.0
11  G3  Bombus_terrestris     9     290.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.assign(diff_length=df1.join(df1.groupby(['Groups',df1.Name.str.contains('BLOC')])
                                .transform(max)['Value'].rename('col1'))
    .groupby('Groups').col1
           .transform(lambda ss:ss.max()-ss.min()))

 Groups               Name  Value  diff_length
0      G1  BLOC_Homo_sapiens    100           80
1      G1    BLOC_Chimpenzee     99           80
2      G1        BLOC_Bonobo     80           80
3      G1        Canis_lupus     20           80
4      G1        Danio_rerio     10           80
5      G2  BLOC_Homo_sapiens     30            2
6      G2        BLOC_Bonobo     29            2
7      G2       Mus_musculus     28            2
8      G2      Cules_pupiens     26            2
9      G3      BLOC_Gorrilla    300          290
10     G3  Cimex_lectularius     10          290
11     G3  Bombus_terrestris      9          290
```